# No operation which satisfies the runtime constraints found for "context"

Tags: neoscms

I am having neos with version 1.1.0 beta1

When i try to change page layout

I got below error

```
Failed to render element
pagetwocolum<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/
body<TYPO3.TypoScript:Template>/
content/
main<TYPO3.Neos:PrimaryContent>/
default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
element<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection>/
__meta/
cache/
maximumLifetime
No operation which satisfies the runtime constraints found for "context". (20140614122525674a6d)
```

and in log it says

```
flow/Data/Temporary/Production/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Eel_FlowQuery_FlowQuery.php: No operation which satisfies the runtime constraints found for "context".
```

Could you please let me know what causes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are rendering a missing ContentCollection node for the layout `pagetwocolumn`. There's a fix in the latest stable version (1.1.2) that gives a better error message if that problem occurs (see https://jira.typo3.org/browse/NEOS-150). With that version you should get a better error message pointing you to a solution.

What's happening in the background is, that the `TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection` object needs a node of type `TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection` on the given `nodePath` (e.g. `main`). You can add these missing nodes (if they are configured as a `childNode`) with the following command (if your page is of type `TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Page`):

```
./flow node:autocreatechildnodes --node-type TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Page
```

Have a look at this documentation page for more information about ContentCollections and how to configure `childNode`: http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/1.1/IntegratorsCookbook/EditableSharedFooter.html